# HSQLDB get next value for IDENTITY column

Tags: auto-increment, identity, hsqldb

I'm looking for a query to get the next `IDENTITY` value of a HSQL table. Like if I were to insert a new row into a table that has an auto id column, what value would that turn into.

I did some research and couldn't find anything sadly.

Example:

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Names (
  id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(16)
)
```

Now I can insert names without having to specify the `id`. Instead it gets added automatically and increments itself with each insert.
Now I'd like to get whatever value will be next (if I don't manually set it).

*Edit:*

I think I found a solution:

```
SELECT
  IDENTITY_START
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME = 'NAMES'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ID'
```

Comment: From the manual: [Example 4.1. inserting the next sequence value into a table row](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#N10DEE)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is talking about sequences. Not the table auto id values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated my question. I also might have found the soltion.

Comment: That gives the starting value of the underlying (unnamed) sequence. That is not the "next value". What do you need that "next value" for? If you need it to populate FK columns for subsequent inserts into other tables you can use `identity()` to retrieve the generates value _after_ inserting. Another option is to define the `IDENTITY` column based on a (named) sequence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the use case would be showing the user which ID will be next. And there are other related use cases.

Comment: Then use a sequence. But showing the user generated ID values is a bad idea in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last identity value already inserted, but not the next one.

Use the `IDENTITY()` function. The value is useful for inserting into another table which has a foreign key referencing the `Names` table. For example,

```
  INSERT INTO OtherTable VALUES DEFAULT, IDENTITY(), 'A reference to Names table'
```

See the Guide, http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_system_functions

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the value is bound to a session and I only ever get the last value that was used. If I'm using two tables this becomes useless.

Comment: @BrainStone If you have two different sessions then get the inserted ID in one session immediately after doing the insert by doing `CALL IDENTITY()`, like this: `INSERT...; CALL IDENTITY();`, the ID will be the value returned by this SQL query. Then you can use this ID wherever you need.